# Ahead of Time compilation static analysis error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've pin-pointed the problem to exported functions.

animations.ts:

```
export function slideInRight(triggerName = 'slideInRight', unactivatedState = 'initial', activatedState = 'state-0', duration = '1s') {
  return trigger(triggerName, [
    state(unactivatedState, style({
      transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
    })),
    state(activatedState, style({
      transform: 'translateX(0)'
    })),
    transition(`${unactivatedState} => ${activatedState}`, animate(`${duration} ease-in-out`)),
    transition(`${activatedState} => ${unactivatedState}`, animate(`${duration} ease-in-out`))
  ]);
}
```

home.component.ts:

```
import { slideInRight } from 'animations'

@Component({
  // ...
  animations: [slideInRight('param1', 'param2')]
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

I get the following error when attempting to do AOT compilation:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 24:16 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol slideInLeft in path/to/project/angular/animations.ts, resolving symbol HomeComponent in path/to/project/angular/app/pages/home/home.component.ts, resolving symbol HomeComponent in path/to/project/angular/app/pages/home/home.component.ts

If I comment out this the animations property on the decorator call, the error goes away. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem using template strings for animations.  Try refactoring your transitions to use normal string concatenation:

```
transition(unactivatedState + ' => ' + activatedState, animate(duration + ' ease-in-out')),
transition(activatedState + ' => ' + unactivatedState, animate(duration + ' ease-in-out'))
```

]);

Answer (score 0):

Here's some syntax that worked for me:

```
animations: [
    fadeInOut(),
],
```

And:

```
export function fadeInOut(): AnimationEntryMetadata {
    return trigger("fadeInOut", [
        state("in", style({opacity: "1"})),
        transition("void => *", [
            style({opacity: "1"}),
            animate(100),
        ]),
        transition("* => void", [
            animate(100, style({opacity: "0.0"})),
        ]),
    ]);
 }
```

It's been a while, but if I remember correctly I received a similar error at one point when I called a method within fadeInOut() that was not statically analyzable by the ahead of time compiler. My solution at that time was to make my animation method completely self-contained.

Comment: What do you mean completely self-contained?

Comment: I updated my question with the actual method. Can you point out what the issue is?

Comment: When I said 'completely self-contained', I meant that I had been calling helper functions (fadeIn and fadeOut) that I'd written when the AOT compiler was complaining. I refactored so I wasn't relying on those helper functions. As regards your second question, I'm not sure at the moment. It looks like the AOT compiler is complaining about 'slideInLeft': "Expression form not supported (position 24:16 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol slideInLeft.'" But I'm not seeing slideInLeft anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Well I have multiple functions, the `slideInLeft` function is nearly identical to the `slideInRight` function. Just some string changes and css style changes.